# Table row selection method gives out alerts many times instead of just one time

Tags: jquery

I have the below code in JS. I am finding the table row selected successfully on double click, but my problem is the method takes some time as it loops through more times then necessary.
Can someone pl. point out what Iam missing in this javascript-jquery code so that the method alerts only one time and not multiple times.

**JS**

```
function selectTableRowData(){

   $(document).on('dblclick', '#tableSectionDetails tbody tr', (function(){
    var caseId = $(this).closest("tr").find("select").val();

    alert (caseId); //alerts multiple times

    } 
}));
```

}

**JSP**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover spacer-top" id="tableSectionDetails" name="tableSectionDetails" ondblclick="selectTableRowData();return false;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr >
                            <th class="text-center">Section name </th>
                            <th class="text-center">SubSection name (if exists)</th>
                            <th class="text-center">Case Name </th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                         <c:forEach var="section" items="${sectionList}">
                            <c:if test="${section.subSectionList.size()==0}">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>${section.sectionName}</td>
                                    <td>-</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select id="selectCaseName" name ="selectCaseName" class="form-control">
                                                <c:forEach var="scase" items="${section.SCaseList}">
                                                    <option value="${scase.id}">${scase.caseName}</option>
                                                </c:forEach>  
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </c:if> <!-- if subsection ==0 -->
                            <c:if test="${section.subSectionList.size()==1}">

                                <tr> 
                                    <td>${section.sectionName}</td>
                                    <td>${section.subSectionList.get(0).subSectionName}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select id="selectCaseName" name ="selectCaseName" class="form-control">
                                                <c:forEach var="scase" items="${section.subSectionList.get(0).SCaseList}">
                                                    <option value="${scase.id}">${scase.caseName}</option>
                                                </c:forEach>  
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </c:if>     <!--end   subsection ==1 -->
                            <c:if test="${section.subSectionList.size()>1}">
                                <c:forEach var="subSection" items="${section.subSectionList}">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>${section.sectionName}</td>
                                        <td>${subSection.subSectionName}</td>

                                        <td>
                                            <select id="selectCaseName" name ="selectCaseName" class="form-control">
                                                    <c:forEach var="scase" items="${subSecction.SCaseList}">

                                                        <option value="${scase.id}">${scase.caseName}</option>
                                                    </c:forEach>  
                                            </select>

                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </c:forEach> <!-- subsection loop end -->
                            </c:if>     <!-- if subSection > 1 -->
                         </c:forEach> <!-- section loop end --> 

                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Comment: I created a fiddle with the provided code, and it only alerts once per double click. Are you perhaps running your selectTableRowData() function more than one time? The listeners only need to be attached once - every time you run that function it creates a new set of listeners and attaches them.

Comment: No, havent attached listeners more than once. Attaching it only when this method is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<table>` tag has the function selectTableRowData() bound to it's double-click event. Then in the selectTableRowData() function, you create listeners and bind the code to the double-click event. This means that you have an event handler creating more event handlers *each* time you double-click. These listeners do not go away unless you unbind them.

So the first time you click, you bind a set which means one alert; the second time you click you have two listeners, so two alerts, etc. Try running selectTableRowData() only once, after your table is created.

Comment: that worked perfectly well. Thank you for the clarification, I did miss that point.

Answer (score 1):

The event handler `selectTableRowData()` bound to double-click event adds event listeners on the  elements and the event propagates on the double click and multiple new listeners are created.

Solution:

Stop the propagation of new listeners on the double click by passing the event as parameter to function `selectTableRowData()` using `event.stopPropogation`. I have created a [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/puvukami/1/edit) solution using Knockout for data-binding.